# How customer email responses will be saved on CaseComment? What will be the CreatedBy name on case comment?

Tags: email2case, case-comment

Basically, I have a question on how customer replies are stored in case comment? I wanted to know what it will show in Created By field?

Answer (score 1):

By default, when using [On-demand Email-to-case](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customizesupport_enabling_on_demand_email_to_case.htm&type=5), replies are stored as Emails, not as Case Comments & Created By is the **Automated Case User**.